# id where column has two conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of customers that join and leave a company

```
ID ActiveFrom ActiveTo
```

I have for example a where clause that has

```
where ActiveFrom <= '20170101' 
  and Activeto < '20170201'
```

but some times a customer has decided to re-join the company a few days later because of a deal.

example customer:

```
ID ActiveFrom ActiveTo
1  2000-01-01 2017-01-03
1  2017-01-28 Null
2  2000-01-01 2017-01-06
```

I want to exclude the customers that do this, from the customers that leave the company but come back

so I want id 2 to be returned only

please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this.

```
SELECT * FROM Customer C1
WHERE C1.ActiveFrom <= '20170101' 
        AND C1.Activeto < '20170201'
        AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM Customer C2
                WHERE C1.ID = C2.ID
                AND C2.ActiveTo IS NULL )
```

Comment: this is brill thank you, what's great is to change the C2.ActiveTo IS NULL to c2.ActiveFrom >= '20170101', this is fab thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could use a subquery on `WHERE` statement:

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE (SELECT id FROM tablename WHERE activeTo is null) <> id
GROUP By id
```

You can find more information here:
https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/subqueries.php